# Books on using SAS to analyze market risk

Tags: references, sas, finance, risk

Is there a book that teaches you how to use SAS to analyze the market risk of a portfolio of stocks,bonds and options?

Answer (score 0):

check out an old book from SAS Publising on [Stock Market Analysis Using the SAS® System: Portfolio Selection and Evaluation](http://www.sas.com/store/books/categories/usage-and-reference/stock-market-analysis-using-the-sas-system-portfolio-selection-and-evaluation/prodBK_55043_en.html)